# initialize iterator error C++ in gcc compiler

Tags: c++, dictionary, gcc, iterator

So i am initializing an iterator through a map like this:

```
std::map<K, V>::iterator it = m_map.find(begin);
```

And I am using a GCC(7.2.0) compiler that is giving me these errors:

> 1.prog.cc:187:9: error: need 'typename' before 'unit_test::std::map::iterator' because 'unit_test::std::map' is a dependent scope
>            std::map::iterator it = m_map.find(begin);
>   2. prog.cc:187:34: error: expected ';' before 'it'
>            std::map::iterator it = m_map.find(begin);

I didn't think that I was initializing it wrong, but i would appreciate if anyone can help and knows what I have to change.

Comment: You need to use `typename` *just like the error message tells you to do*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the iterator's type hard-coded, you can simply use the `auto` keyword:

```
auto it = m_map.find(begin);
```

This way, the type of `it` will be deduced from its initializer ( `m_map.find(begin)` in this case).